# How can I pass and save C/C++ pointers to C#, and return them back, using Mono Project

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, mono

I'm having a serious problem figuring out how to pass and store effectively C pointers to C#, and then returning them back when I need them with Mono. I'm building a scripting layer with C# on top of C++. For example (pseudocode):

C++:

```
GameObject* owner = new GameObject();
void* args[1] = {owner};
return_object = mono_runtime_invoke("InitReference", mono_object, args, &exception);
```

C#: (C# GameObject class instance)

```
public IntPtr InitReference(IntPtr game_object_ptr)
{
    return game_object_ptr;
}
```

What I want to achieve is a relation between the C++ object instance and the actual C# representation. There is little information about this, and I'm a little lost.

Comment: Just a suggestion but C# doesn't lend itself to a scripting language that well. Perhaps you can use lua instead and use something like: https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2/tree/sol3

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:
New a .Net struct which has StructLayout attribute, like:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Explicit )]
public struct GameObject
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public int Id;
  ......
}
```

then .net pointer can point the struct instance.

Answer (score 0):

After some trying i solved my problem:
First I stored my pointer address into a char buffer, and then I passed it to mono as an array of ints int[]. This allowed my pointer adress to stay alive in the C# environment, and I'm able to retrieve it whenever I want.